# What is the easiest way to check if my Powershell script is executed as system?

Tags: powershell

I want to check from my script if it's executed as system.
What is the easiest way to do so?

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085744/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-windows-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name`

Example

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

Cudo's to [Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2085759/52598)

Answer (score 0):

The user that runs the script should be available in the variable `$env:username`.

Example:

```
if ($env:username -eq 'SYSTEM') {
  # do stuff
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns the computer account name. For example- "DESKTOP-7823$"

Comment: That's strange. You can check if `$env` contains other helpful attributes with `Get-Childitem env:`.

Comment: At least, if it always contains the computername, you can compare it with `$env:COMPUTERNAME`.